# Pandas DF dtype attribute

Tags: python, pandas

When calling the dtypes attribute on a pandas data frame, the last line of the output is usually `dtype: object`.  For example:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd
In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame({'numbers':100,'floats': 5.75,'name':'Jill'},index=['a'])
In [3]: df.dtypes
Out[3]: 
numbers  int64
floats float64
name    object
dtype: object
```

What is the `dtype: object` line referring to in the output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pandas.DataFrame.dtypes` is a `pd.Series` object, so that's just the dtype of the Series that holds your dtypes!

```
>>> type(df.dtypes)
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

That makes sense, since it holds `numpy.dtype` objects:

```
>>> df.dtypes.map(type)
numbers    <class 'numpy.dtype'>
floats     <class 'numpy.dtype'>
name       <class 'numpy.dtype'>
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

`object` here refer to `not number` or mixed data type : which will include `string|list|dict..`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'numbers':100,'floats': 5.75,'name':'Jill'},index=['a'])

df.applymap(type)
Out[7]: 
         numbers           floats           name
a  <class 'int'>  <class 'float'>  <class 'str'>
```

Notice when the column is mixed with number and other type , it still object

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Mix':[111,'notnumber']})
df.dtypes
Out[10]: 
Mix    object
dtype: object
```

However when we check each cell, it will return the cell type which contain at least two different types

```
df.applymap(type)
Out[11]: 
             Mix
0  <class 'int'>
1  <class 'str'>
```